# Is Field Pack v2.x compatible with EE v2.5.x?

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack

Pixel and Tonic, could one of you please confirm whether or not Field Pack is compatible with EE v2.5.x?

Thanks
Brendan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use at least EE2.6 to use Field Pack v2. The ability to have multiple fieldtypes in a single package was not added until 2.6.

In the change log:

**[Reactor: Added ability to have multiple fieldtypes in one add-on package.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-6-0)** under the Developers heading is what allows for the new Field Pack to work.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. I guess you upgrade to EE v2.6.x then you upgrade to Field Pack v2.x? I've been updating all my other addons before I do the upgrade.

Comment: It depends on the add-on. For field pack I knew that it used the new multi-fieldtype in a single add-on package so I upgraded it after my 2.6 upgrade. Most others still have before 2.6 computability so I was able to upgrade them before I upgraded to 2.6

Comment: Yeah, I think Field Pack will be one of the few that you need to do 'after' you move up to 2.6.x and beyond. Thanks your help.